# L3 Select w/ Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, laravel-3

I'm using laravel 3 do to eager loading. What I've noticed is it works great! Until I use either `->select(['fields')` or `->paginate( , ['fields'])` to select a subset of the model's attributes. When I do this, it automatically culls any eager loaded model, which results in the relationship being NULL. Any clean way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to also select the fields of the relationship table:

```
->select(array(
    'table1.column',
    'table2.column',
    ...
));
```

Comment: Works w/ joins... but not with eager loading, e.g. model::with('relationship')->select(['model.column','relationship.column']) will only pull model.column

Comment: You're right. I was inspecting the code, and apparently there is no way of doing this without modifying the framework (not even with an anonymous function with $query->select(...);).